# Is it possible to use timthumb.php inside JSP page

Tags: jsp, timthumb

I want to use timthumb.php for image resizing/cropping but my project is Java EE.

Is is possible to use something like this in my jsp page ?

```
 <div class="item" style="background: url('timthumb.php?src=http://www.products.com/img/main-banner-slider/updated_banner/promo2_thumb.jpg&w=900&q=100%') no-repeat center 0;') no-repeat center 0;">
```

Any possible ways and kind suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you load a PHP processor into your app container (not impossible, but not [easy](http://php.net/manual/en/java.servlet.php)) you best bet is to write your own image re-sized. [JMagick](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a great library to deal with this though I tend to use BufferedImages for it.

Also in your example you aren't actually trying to use PHP inside JSP, but rather you are referencing a PHP script in some CSS. There is no requirement that CSS reference an image on the same server (or even the same port (as long as you aren't using HTTPS))